# Not connect bottom point and top point in a line chart plotly

Tags: plotly

I am trying to plot this graph [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTwG3.png), which is about a trajectory of an object, if it comes out on one side (bottom), it appears on the other side (top), so I don't want the lines that connect these two points every single time it occurs. 
What I want is a picture like [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGkps.png) using plotly; to achieved this I used 'None' value to indicate the gaps as it's indicated in plotly python line-charts documentation. I have a lot of data in the first picture and it's difficult to change the values to 'None' by hand. Is there a way to do what I want with a big amount of data?

Answer (score 0):

Cause you provide no code or something else I tried a solution for you in javascript.

Here is a jsFiddle that should does your desired behaviour automatically. https://jsfiddle.net/n8v85vL5/

All you must to do is providing the variable `yDifferenceOnThatPointsShouldNotConnected` which is setted in the example to `500`. This means, all points, that have a bigger difference than 500 will not be connected. (respectively the code fill in a null value to achieve that).

So it makes: `trace1.x:[1,2], trace1.y: [5,599]`

to:`trace1.x:[1,1.0001,2], trace1.y: [5,null,599]`

Cause we inserted a null value to y we must insert a x value too. At this I add 0.0001 to the xValue before (in example jsFiddle line 34).

hope it helps:-) I guess you need it in python: This should be possible, just change the syntax to python

Comment: Your solution solves the problem, but I woudn't like to do it "manually" which means iterating over all the values, because I have 35000 rows per file and I need to analyze 48 files. What I would like to know is if there is a parameter or other way that can do exactly what you did, but not iterating over the whole rows.

Thanks a lot for your answer and time!

Comment: I don't think so that there is any parameter for that behaviour, cause this is very specific. And I think it should be no problem to iterating over 48 x 35000 rows. I guess the iterates itself only needs max. a second in whole. btw: you can improve the performance while iterating over the row with avoiding jquery $.each loops and use plain for-java script loops.